# How to securely manage connectionstring in production environment of Dotnet Core Project?

Tags: .net-core, production-environment

I need to manage production database connection string insecure way for Dotnet core project

Comment: Your application running on Azure or on-premise?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan On-Premise